# "Alphabeticalized" or "alphabetical zed"?

Tags: orthography

In [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=alphabeticalized), if I search for the word *alphabeticalized*, many links show that there is a word *alphabeticalized*.  But in MS Word 2007 , if I type *alphabeticalized* then it underlines that word and suggests *'Alphabetical zed'* as an option.

What's the correct spelling?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is [Alphabetized](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alphabetised). It looks like MS Word is trying to split your word into two correct words. There are relatively few results on Google for alphabeticalized.

Answer (score 5):

The correct word is *Alphabetized*. *Alphabeticalize* or *Alphabeticalized* is not a proper English word (You can check English dictionaries; it has no entry.). Since MS Word suggests the closest match, it says *Alphabetical zed*, which has nothing to do with *Alphabeticalized*.

Answer (score 1):

The OED gives *alphabetize* with the two meanings

> To express or symbolize by alphabetic letters; to reduce to
>   (alphabetic) writing

and

> To arrange alphabetically.

There is no entry for *alphabeticalize*.

It also records *alphabet* as a verb, giving Johnson’s definition *to range in the order of the alphabet* and one of the citations includes the past participle *alphabeted*.

Comment: I came to english.stackexchange.com to find out why wiktionary thinks "alphabet" is a verb. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alphabet - I've never seen/heard it used this way (always use alphabetize myself). Is this really a verb, has it ever been a verb?

Comment: It’s rare. The OED’s most recent citation for the verb is this from 1954: ‘Does the sequence of content follow classified, chronologic, . . . or alphabetic order? If alphabetic, are the topics large or small? How are they alphabeted?’

Answer (score 0):

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=alphabeticalize)

**alphabeticalize**

A word that doesn't exist but is commonly confused with alphabetize.

There is no telling if some specialized jargon has defined the word to suit its needs. Which is probably why Google comes up with so many references.